# JQuery UI autocomplete broken in JQuery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

Since updating to the latest JQuery I have noticed that all my getJson calls stopped working, so I have been changing them one by one to '$.ajax' requests and setting "dataType: 'text json'".

However I have just noticed that my JQuery UI autocomplete usages have also stopped working, I assume this is because somewhere down the line it has a faulty call to getJson.

What is the best way to go about fixing this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: jQuery 1.5+ won't parse invalid JSON, so make sure it is valid using JSONLint (http://www.jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather unexpected..... Here's a question I asked about it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323357/unable-to-get-response-using-jquery-getjson-with-mvc3)

Comment: I downloaded an applied the patches plugin and it does not appear to have fixed the getJson method? Is there anymore information I should be following?

Comment: @Alex.. could you possibly stick a code sample (server and client) up?

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it using this code

```
$("#Keywords").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'text json',
            success: function(data) { response(data); }
            url: $.format(
                "{0}?term={1}&{2}",
                "@Url.Action("SearchAutoComplete", "Report")",
                request['term'], getUrl()),
        });
    }
});
```

Had to change the source to a function which implements '.ajax' instead of '.getJson'.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: That's intriguing.. I've managed to return plenty of jason using the normal method once I'd got over my initial hurdle.